# Data Analysis when Reading a .xls File using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am working on a data analysis project in Python. I have an .xls file that I need to read and get certain information from each line. I am using xlrd.

When I open the file in notepad, the first ten lines are comments about what the file contains, and then I get to the actual data. How do I skip all the lines beginning with "#"?

Also, once I get to the rows, I want to iterate through each row and separate the elements in each column of each row and add it to a dictionary for each column. How would I separate data in each row based on the column ?

As of now, here is my code:

```
    peaksheets = peakfile.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
    num_rows = peaksheets.nrows -1
    curr_row = -1
    while curr_row < num_rows:
            curr_row +=1
            row = str(peaksheet.row(curr_row))
            words = row.strip().split('\t')
            c = words[0]
            s = int(words[1])
```

I am also getting the following error when I run my code:

```
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '# This f'
```

Which is why I want to skip the lines starting with the "#" symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pandas to read the file to a dataframe.  If you really need the data in a dictionary, you can pass it to one from the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls', 'Sheet1', skiprows=range(10))
datadict = df.to_dict(orient='dict')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
peaksheets = peakfile.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
dict_data = {}
num_rows = peaksheets.nrows -1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row +=1
        # we want to skip the comments
        if row.startswith('#'):
            continue
        row = str(peaksheet.row(curr_row))
        words = row.strip().split('\t')
        for i in range(len(words)):
            dict_data[curr_row][i] = words[i]
        c = words[0]
        s = int(words[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first 10 lines are the only ones you don't want in, you could always just start `curr_row` at 10.  As for your dictionary, try the following:

```
headers=[(names of the columns to use as keys for your dict)]
dict_list=[]
col_list=[None]*len(headers)    
for curr_row in range(10, peaksheets.nrows):
    for curr_cell in range(peaksheets.ncols):
        cell_value = str(peaksheets.cell(curr_row, curr_cell).value)
        col_list[curr_row].append(cell_value)

for head_name in headers:
    dict_list[head_name]=col_list[headers.index(head_name)]
```

A few things to keep in mind:

1. This code assumes you want every column
2. This requires you to structure the `headers` list in the order the columns appear in the sheet
3. This should be a replacement to your `while` loop.
4. If there are more comments, you can check if the first element of the row is a '#', and ignore it.